# how to desactivate double indent when I paste the code in a python terminal

Tags: python, paste

I try to understand why my pasting in my terminal (linux) in my python interpreter put double indent every line for example :
if I paste these lines :

```
def function(string):
    final = ''
    for i in string:
        try:
            final += str(int(i))
        except ValueError:
            return int(final)
```

I'll get this in my terminal :

```
    ent>>> def function(string):
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>     final = ''
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    final = ''
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> 
>>>     for i in string:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    for i in string:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>
```

And more and more... because when there is a for or any instruction that needs a tab, it return it directly instead to wait for the next instruction,so it rise an IndentationError:

And I realize that if I paste this for exemple :

```
import mathimport threading
```

it will paste like this in my terminal :

```
>>> import math
>>> import threading
>>>
```

I didn't have from the beginin, so any idea ? because it was impossible to find my answer in internet..

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the source indentation, are all tabs or spaces, are they mixed?

Comment: You weren't getting extra *indentation*; you were getting extra *newlines*, which caused the REPL to try to understand each line of code separately (as in the linked duplicate). You were probably getting the extra newlines because of some dos vs unix line ending issue. Notice for example that the "working" code looks like it's on the same line on Stack Overflow, because it's not treating whatever character you have in there for a newline, as an actual newline in the *Stack Overflow post* source.

Answer (score 0):

They are mixed, if we see my first code, it's only one indentation, and then the second line is one tab and one indentation, and from the fourth line it's two tabs, as simply as we see on my question.
And if I paste it in any other text editor it work perfectly, I tried to see every setting in my terminal or in my linux but I've found nothing so far... It's really strange !

Edit :

Apparently for a reason that I don't know, it come from Atom the editor that I use for writing my python code.

I explain it's very strange !

if I copy the code from Atom, and I paste it in any other text editor (there, in kate or other) and I copy from this other editor and paste in my terminal, it's happend again, double indendation.

But to correct that I just create a new fil in Atom, and then is fine, It work properly the pasting in the terminal.

Question solved, but why ?? That's a mystery ^^